# Where will this AsyncTask run?

Tags: android

Say I have this code in the `AlertDialog.Builder(context)` of my application. The question is in which `Thread` will it run?

```
final Thread myPrettyOperation = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Do some really long operation.
    }
};
class MyPrettyTask extends
        AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {
    protected Boolean doInBackground(
            Void... voids) {
        myPrettyOperation.start();
        return true;
    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(
            Integer... progress) {
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    }
}
new MyPrettyTask().execute();
```

Comment: Question is not really clear for me, what are you exactly trying to find out. I think its just to create 3 threads one inside each one and eventually will perform 'long operation' that is it. Each thread will just keep creating new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked an additional question in your comment to Vipul Shah's reply, I'll answer it here (it requires a code block). Your question was:

> Are you sure about this? *[whether it all runs on the UI thread]* How can I investigate this more?

With the code block I posted below.

Notice the Log.i calls that I injected into your code. Run your application, and check the logcat output. The threads names' will be listed with lines started with "Thread1:", "Thread2:", "Thread3:", respectively. Wherever you see "main" in the output, it will mean your UI thread. In other cases, you will see the thread's name, e.g. "Thread14" for your myPrettyOperation.

```
final Thread myPrettyOperation = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.i("YOUR_TAG", "Thread1: "+ Thread.currentThread().getName()); 
        //Do some really long operation.
    }
};
class MyPrettyTask extends
        AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {
    protected Boolean doInBackground(
            Void... voids) {
        Log.i("YOUR_TAG", "Thread2: "+ Thread.currentThread().getName()); 
        myPrettyOperation.start();
        return true;
    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(
            Integer... progress) {
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    }
}
new MyPrettyTask().execute();
Log.i("YOUR_TAG", "Thread3: "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends which parts of the code you posted are considered. There are 3 threads involved in your code.

Obviously, the body of run() will run in the thread **you created for myPrettyOperation**.

The lines *"myPrettyOperation.start(); return true;"* will run in a **thread allocated from the thread pool** of the system for the AsyncTask.

The rest of the code will **run on the UI thread** (i.e. on the main thread) **of your application**.

Answer (score 0):

> Say I have this code in the AlertDialog.Builder(context) of my
>   application

It will always run on UI Thread

Comment: Are you sure about this? How can I investigate this more?